# Permutations of a word if you can use both uppercase and lowercase

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I know how I would arrange letters of a word if only uppercase or lowercase was allowed, but how would I solve a problem when each letter can be either?

For example, for the letters ANAGRAM using only uppercase, the number of arrangements would just be $7!/3!$.

However, what if something like AnaGraM or aNagRAM was allowed and they are considered different from each other? How many arrangements of these letters would there be if both uppercase and lowercase were allowed?

Answer (score 1):

You know how many ways there are to choose an ordering of letters, without taking case into account. Now for each of these you have two options for each letter in turn: lowercase or uppercase. These choices are independent, so each ordering of letters corresponds to $2^n$ different arrangements, where $n$ is the length of the string.

Comment: I originally left a comment which I have now deleted.  I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: There is a subtlety here.  Choosing whether each A is uppercase or lowercase affects the number of repeated letters.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig No, there isn't. Just choose the order of letters first and the cases second.